# Flask Systemd Service not able open video file under s3 bucket mounted folder

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, python, services, amazon-s3

My flask app is running as service but it is not able to read video file from s3bucket mounted folder. OpenCV does not throw error when it fails to load but returns 0 frame array. So we understand that it is not able to read from s3 bucket path.

Service file

```
[Unit]
Description=service
After=network.target
        
[Service]
User=ubuntu
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/src/my-service
Environment=PATH=/home/ubuntu/src/my-service/venv/bin
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/src/my-service/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini my-service.ini
        
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

s3 Bucket videos are under

```
/home/ubuntu/src/s3Bucket/video
```

I am able to read from s3Bucket/video if I would create new python file and run it manually, but can not read from service application. Also, service can read files under

```
/home/ubuntu/src
```

But service can not read files under

```
/home/ubuntu/src/s3Bucket/video
```

Tried different service file options, but could not figure out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply remove group=www-data from systemd file. It is all about permissions.